# What is the replacement for Perwebrequest life style Castle.Windsor in .net core?

Tags: .net, .net-core, castle-windsor, castle

net core castle windsor does not have Perwebrequest life style 
What is the replacement for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the research I did
in .net core **scope** life style replaced with **PerWebRequest** because in .net core system.web removed

Comment: So, `LifestyleScoped()` then?

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET-CORE you would use:

```
LifestyleCustom<MsScopedLifestyleManager>()
```

from the package - https://github.com/volosoft/castle-windsor-ms-adapter